# how to add in uiview for images to button programmaticaly in iphone

Tags: iphone

im new to iphone development.here i added some images to button in uiview programmaticaly in iphone. Here my problem is i want to add some more images in uiview. i added next and previous buttons in view .if  click nextbutton some more will displayed in next view. i tried  but i dont no how to displayed  programmaticaly some more images when i click nextbutton in iphone.

can any one plz help me for my problem.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UIImageView to the view and then do:

```
myUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"anImageInMyBundle"];
```

Now, if you want to have a bunch of images and go through them systematically, you have a few options. This is going to depend on what your app actually does.

If you're displaying local images that are in your bundle, you can just create an NSArray (mutable or immutable - per the situation) and add all your UIImages to it at run time.

If your app downloads data from the web, you're probably going to start making network calls in a secondary thread that downloads and sets the next image. Give us a better idea of what your app does, and we might be able to provide more specific code/examples.

Comment: i want to displayed 30 images in uiview with button.first i displayed 10 images in uiview. i added buttons like next and previous buttons. when i click next buttonsome more images are displayed in next view. in programmaticaly how to added this some more images in next view. plz help me.

Comment: Add a screenshot to your question. Are you showing ten images in one UIView? Are the images always the same ones? Where are they loaded from?

Comment: ya im shwed ten images in one uiview

Comment: Ok. Where do you get the images? Are they in your bundle?